# Is there a way to access gallery from a dialog?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

so me and 2 friends we're doing a work where we need to enter products and then edit them if we wish so, and when we create and edit them , we've decided to do so in a pop-up(a dialog)... the image below is our pop-up to create a product... where it's supposed to add an image from the gallery when pressing that plus button . Can someone tell us if its possible to do so? or if it need to be an activity instead of a dialog(pop-up). The plus image its a framelayout background. If the code helps ask for it i will provide it! **Thank you in advance!**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can access your gallery from a dialogue you can use this code as a hint

```
private void uploadImage() {

        if(filePath != null)
        {
            final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
            progressDialog.show();
            StorageReference ref = storageReference.child("images/"+ UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            ref.putFile(filePath)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(Newsfeed2.this, "Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            edtDescription.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("my_users").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
                                    String userName = (String) snapshot.child("username").getValue();
                                    userNames.add(userName);
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                                }
                            });

                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(Newsfeed2.this, "Failed "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            double progress = (100.0*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()/taskSnapshot
                                    .getTotalByteCount());
                            progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded "+(int)progress+"%");
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: So that function is supposed to be called on the click listener of the framelayout on my dialog? Where do you get the filepath?

Comment: Yes you must add that. And for the file path you will be directed to your files folder and inside it you will open the gallery and choose